# How to wait for promise in a forEach in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise

I would like to retrieve an array from my mongodb collection, and before sending it back to the client, work with it.
My desired outcome would be the following:

- Get array from collection_A
- Do the desired work with the array I just got, by having another mongodb query
- Pass the array back to the client

My current code looks like this:

```
                db.collection("collection")
                .find()
                .toArray()
                .then((arr) => {
                    arr.forEach(cur => {
                        db.collection("another-collection")
                            .count({key: cur.prop})
                            .then((retrieved) => {
                                cur.prop = retrieved; //The amount of count one live above
                                //This part runs later than the res.success below
                            })
                            .catch((err: any) => {
                                //Handle error
                            });
                    });
                    return arr;
                })
                .then(arr => {
                    res.success(arr);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    //Handle error
                });
```

At the moment, the work I want to do with the retrieved array happens after `res.success()`, so on the client I will get the original array.
Why is that so?

Comment: I'm quite sure it's the same problem, but I don't know how to implement the solution in my code

Comment: Try using `for-of` instead of `foreach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) along with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
.then((arr) => 
    Promise.all(arr.map(cur => 
        db.collection("another-collection")
            .count({
                key: cur.prop
            })
            .then((retrieved) => {
                cur.prop = retrieved; 
                return curr;
            })
            .catch((err: any) => {
                //Handle error
            })
    ))
)
```

Comment: This way the array I'm sending back in success is undefined for some reasons

Comment: @D.Albert Do you have a return statement in `.then` after `db.collection(...)`? If not, add return `curr` or whatever you want to return.

Comment: I'm not sure at which part should I put the return statement. Can you please demonstrate it in your code? If Promise.all returns a promise with the device, then I suppose I should put it after promise.all, however my IDE shows unreachable code for the below part.

Comment: @D.Albert I've updated my answer, but it's not exactly clear what you want to return as the result.

Comment: I want to manipulate every element of the array I got from the first query, then return the manipulated array to send it back to the client

Comment: @D.Albert Change `return retrieved;` in my edited answer to `return curr;` then.